# »Karlsruhe, den 29. Juli 2012« – warum »den«?

Tags: grammatical-case, time

Wenn man in einem Schriftstück den Ort und das Datum schreibt, dann kenne ich das so:

> [Ort], den [Datum]

also z.B.:

> Karlsruhe, den 29. Juli 2012

Warum schreibt man *den*? Warum nicht *der* wie in Folgendem?

> Es ist der 29. Juli 2012.

Gibt es eine offizielle Quelle (z.B. Duden oder eine Norm), die besagt, dass man *den* schreibt?

Comment: http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibregeln/datum

Comment: http://www.deutschegrammatik20.de/der-einfache-satz/datum/

Comment: http://hypermedia.ids-mannheim.de/call/public/fragen.ansicht?v_kat=23&v_id=3185&v_wort=Datumsangabe (umfassend und sehr interessant!)

Comment: scheinbar is nicht nur der Dativ dem Genitiv sein Tod aber auch der Nominativ dem Akkusativ seiner ;))

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Im Deutschen gibt es zwei Möglichkeiten, ein Datum zu bestimmen:

1. Mit einer Präposition, zum Beispiel *am* (an + dem)

- am Dienstag
- am 10. August
- am kommenden Sonntag
- am Pfingstmontag
- an Neujahr

2. mit dem Akkusativ der Zeit:

- nächsten Samstag
- Berlin, den 12. Oktober
- kommende Woche
- letztes Jahr
- "Wir ziehen diesen Herbst nach Hamburg."

Wenn zwei Bezeichnungen für den gleichen Tag nebeneinander stehen, ist es grammatikalisch naheliegend und korrekt, wenn beide Ausdrücke im gleichen Fall stehen. Entweder im Dativ mit *am*:

> Am Samstag, dem 4. Mai, feiern wir unseren Hochzeitstag.

Oder im adverbialen Akkusativ:

> Letzten Freitag, den 23. Dezember, hatten wir frei.

Bei den letzten Beispielen ist der Monatstag eine Apposition (Nachstellung) zum Wochentag. Der Beisatz steht gemäß der grammatischen Regel im gleichen Fall wie sein Bezugswort.

Fehlen nur Beifügungen wie "nächsten, diesen, kommenden", dann ist zwar der Akkusativ des Wochentags nicht mehr erkennbar. Der Monatstag behält aber den kennzeichnenden Artikel "den":

> Sonntag, den 17. Juli, kehren wir zurück.

Das sind also die beiden möglichen Ausdrucksweisen für das Datum: Der Dativ mit *am* und der adverbiale Akkusativ. Im Sprachgebrauch haben sie sich oft vermischt, so dass der Wochentag im Dativ mit *am*, der Monatstag aber im Akkusativ steht:

> Am Sonntag, den 17. Juli kehren wir zurück.

Diese Form wurde früher oft als Fehler angerechnet, weil sie eine Kasusabweichung in der Apposition enthielt. Wer aber das Oben gesagte bedenkt, der erkennt, dass hier ganz einfach zwei voneinander unabhängige Zeitangaben zusammenkommen. Es handelt sich also um keine falsche Apposition, sondern eine Aufzählung. Darum setzen wir auch nach dieser Form des Datums kein Komma.

Diese Schreibweise ist natürlich auch bei der Form ohne am möglich, wenn der Fall, in dem der Wochentag steht, nicht mehr erkennbar ist:

> Sonntag, den 17. Juli kehren wir zurück.

Im Deutschen hat man also die Wahl zwischen der streng grammatikalischen Form der Apposition oder die losere Form der Aufzählung selbständiger Zeitangaben. Man muss allerdings darauf achten, dass bei der Apposition das zweite Komma zu setzen ist und dass man es bei der Aufzählung weglässt. Gebraucht man das Wort *am* gar nicht, dann kann man nichts falsch machen:

> Sonntag, den 17. Juli, kehren wir zurück / Sonntag, den 17. Juli kehren wir zurück.

**Falsch** sind allerdings Datumsbestimmungen mit dem adverbialen Dativ (den es nicht gibt):

> Donnerstag, dem 7. Oktober

oder

> München, dem 12. Februar

([Quelle](http://www.translationdirectory.com/article197.htm))