# "München, den 1.11.2016"

Tags: grammatical-case, time, grammaticality

Angenommen ich schreibe heute eine Bewerbung. Unten müsste ich ja dann das Datum und den Ort hinschreiben.

Also wenn ich München wohne zum Beispiel:

> München, den 1.11.2016

Wieso *den* und nicht *der*? Ich finde, das ergibt grammatikalisch keinen Sinn.

Comment: In jeder Sprache gibt es Redewendungen, die keinen Sinn ergeben. Ein kompletter Satz ist das Ganze sowieso nicht.

Comment: @MartinRosenau: I see. Providing a bit of explanation and evidence/justification would probably yield a satisfactory answer.

Comment: Zeitadverbiale stehen in Akkusativ, und vllt ist es daher

Comment: "Wir schreiben *den* 1.11.2016" - Möglicherweise daher. Der Rechtschreibrat schreibt übrigens "Donnerstag, 16. Februar 2006" in seinen Beispielen, zieht sich also aus der Affäre.

Comment: related: http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/4954/ort-der-datum-oder-ort-den-datum

Comment: @tofro: Ich habe "Hamburg, den 1.1.2011" noch nie zu "Wir schreiben den ..." ergänzt, und wäre selbst nie auf die Idee dieser Ergänzung gekommen. Wieso ergänzt man nicht "Es ist in Hamburg, es ist der 1.1.2011"?

Comment: @userunknown weil Was?

Comment: @tofro: Wie weil was? Von *weil* ist bei mir gar nicht die Rede.

Comment: @userunknown etwas länger, nicht vom Händy: Weil daraufhin sofort die Frage aufkommt "was?". Wir schreiben...: Siehe Star Trek Intro: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=awH9FvLZUCo

Comment: @Tofro: Verstehe weder die Frage, noch den Link. Worauf kommt die Frage "Was?" auf? Startreck: "Wir schreiben das Jahr ...". Kein "den", und Du willst ja kaum behaupten, dass Briefschlußformeln von und seit Startreck so sind. Wieso nicht "Hamburg, am 20.1.1911"?

Answer (score 2):

Sinn per se ergibt es nicht. Aber das tun andere Regeln wie "direkt betroffene Aktanten stehen im Akkusativ, indirekt betroffene im Dativ" im Grunde auch nicht. Trotzdem sind sie nützlich, weil alle MItglieder der Sprachgemeinschaft sich daran halten und dadurch schneller und einfacher kommunizieren können, als wenn alle Valenzrahmen komplett zufällig wären.

Ebenso mit den Zeitausdrücken. Man sagt

> Wir spielten jeden Tag Fußball.

und nicht

> Wir spielten jeder Tag Fußball.

d.h. der Akkusativ wird zur Markierung von Zeitadverbialen verwendet. Das ist an sich willkürlich. *Nicht* willkürlich ist aber die Überstimmung des Gebrauchs bei "jeden Tag" und "Hamburg, den 1.11.", denn zwei verwandte Konstruktionen mit verwandtem Sinn lassen sich leichter merken und verwenden als unterschiedliche Konstruktionen.

Answer (score 1):

wild geraten: Kurzform für "Wir schreiben den 1.11.2016."

Bei einer [Bewerbung nach DIN 5008](http://bewerbung.net/bewerben-nach-din-5008/) wird kein Artikel verwendet. Aus dem dort verwendeten Beispiel wird nur nicht klar, wie das mit den führenden Nullen ist.

Ein umfassender Artikel zum Thema: http://www.annika-lamer.de/so-schreiben-sie-datum-und-uhrzeit-richtig/ . Annika Lamer erwähnt, dass DIN 5008 führende Nullen (für Daten und Uhrzeiten) vorschreibt.

Dafür entfällt laut DIN 5008 der Ort. [Quelle](https://de.wikibooks.org/wiki/Umgangsformen:_Gesch%C3%A4ftsbriefe)

Artikel gibt es nur bei Datumsangaben im Fließtext; und da wird es erst recht kompliziert:

> Die gute Nachricht vorab: Ob Sie den oder dem verwenden, bleibt (meistens) Ihnen überlassen; beides ist korrekt. Die schlechte Nachricht: Richtig knifflig wird’s bei der Zeichensetzung.

(Zitat Annika Lamer)

---

Und dann gibt es noch eine [komplette Website zur DIN 5008](http://www.din-5008-richtlinien.de/startseite/datum/). Hier heißt es:

- Jahreszahl vierstellig
- Tag zweistellig
- Monat zweistellig oder ausgeschrieben
- Außerhalb des Fließtextes können Monatsnamen abgekürzt werden.

Korrekt sind also

> 01.11.2016
>   2016-11-01 (ISO 8601)
>   1. November 2016
>   1. Nov 2016

Comment: Führende Nullen sind ein Artefakt, das aus Formularen mit festen Kästchen für Ziffern herrührt und ergonomisch ungünstig ist. Und die DIN 5008 ist auch für kaum jmd. verbindlich. Dass ein "Wir schreiben" implizit gemeint ist müsste auch erst gezeigt werden, etwa, dass es früher üblich war und sukzessive verdrängt/verkürzt wurde.

Comment: @userunknown Ich sag ja: wild geraten.