# Datum als Überschrift im Schulheft

Tags: grammar-identification

Noch eine Frage zu dieser vertrakten Datumsgeschichte:

Wie sieht es aus, wenn man nur das reine Datum mit Tagesangabe (ohne gedachten adverbialen Akkusativ) als Zeitvermerk, z.B. ins Schulheft schreibt. Dann müsste es doch richtig heißen:

Dienstag, der 12. Februar 2019 (im Sinne von "Heute ist...") und nicht Dienstag, den 12. Februar 2019.

Oder liege ich da falsch?

Comment: Hallo Petra Zaafrani, ich hab zwei kleine Fehler korrigiert: Man schreibt "in das/ins Schulheft" und zwischen Tag (12.) und Monat kommt ein Leerzeichen. Dankesformeln brauchst du auch nicht schreiben, das ist in Stackexchange nicht üblich :)

Comment: Related [question](https://german.stackexchange.com/q/4954/1696).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hierzu gibt es keine allgemeingültige Regel oder Vorschrift. Es kommt immer darauf an, welche Konstruktion der Schreiber für sich hier verkürzt sehen möchte. Dementsprechend hat der Schreiber hierbei einen entsprechend Freiraum und kann wählen.

Wenn wie in der Frage erwähnt das Datum als Kurzform von "Heute ist Dienstag, der 12. Februar." aufgefasst wird, ist die Schreibweise "Dienstag, 12. Februar" korrekt.

Eine Alternative wäre "Geschrieben am Dienstag, den 12. Februar". Dann könnte man das auch abkürzen zu "Dienstag, den 12. Feburar".

Allerdings werden diese beiden Schreibweisen im Allgemeinen als veraltet angesehen. Im geschäftlichen Schriftverkehr ist es heutzutag üblich, die Datumsangabe zu schreiben als

> Dienstag, 12. Februar

wenn man denn den Wochentag aufnehmen möchte. Damit umgeht man natürlich auch elegant die Diskussion ob "der" oder "den" richtig ist. Ich würde daher diese Schreibweise empfehlen.